# Applying Python UDF function per row in a polars dataframe throws unexpected exception 'expected tuple, got list'

Tags: python, dataframe, user-defined-functions, python-polars

I have the following polars DF in Python

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "user_movies": [[7064, 7153, 78009], [6, 7, 1042], [99, 110, 3927], [2, 11, 152081], [260, 318, 195627]],
    "user_ratings": [[5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [4.0, 2.0, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0, 3.0], [3.5, 3.0, 4.0], [1.0, 4.5, 0.5]],
    "common_movies": [[7064, 7153], [7], [110, 3927], [2], [260, 195627]]
})
print(df.head())
```

I want to create a new column named "common_movie_ratings" that will take from each rating list only the index of the movie rated in the common movies. For example, for the first row, I should return only the ratings for movies [7064, 7153,], for the second row the ratings for the movie [7], and so on and so forth.

For this reason, I created the following function:

```py
def get_common_movie_ratings(row): #Each row is a tuple of arrays.
    common_movies = row[2] #the index of the tuple denotes the 3rd array, which represents the common_movies column.
    user_ratings = row[1]
    ratings_for_common_movies= [user_ratings[list(row[0]).index(movie)] for movie in common_movies]
    return ratings_for_common_movies
```

Finally, I apply the UDF function on the dataframe like

```py
df["common_movie_ratings"] = df.apply(get_common_movie_ratings, return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Float64))
```

Every time I apply the function, on the 3rd iteration/row I receive the following error

> expected tuple, got list

[image: Output after every 3rd iteration]

I have also tried a different approach for the UDF function like

```py
def get_common_movie_ratings(row):
   common_movies = row[2]
   user_ratings = row[1]
   ratings = [user_ratings[i] for i, movie in enumerate(row[0]) if movie in common_movies]
   return ratings
```

But again on the 3rd iteration, I received the same error.

#### Update - Data input and scenario scope ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77567521/10623444))

Comment: Are the user movies and ratings always 3 elements?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Νο, they vary in length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What went wrong with your approach

Ignoring performance penalties for python UDFs, there are two things that went wrong in your approach.

1. `apply` which is now [`map_rows`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.map_rows.html#polars.DataFrame.map_rows) in the context that you're trying to use it is expecting the output to be a tuple where each element of the tuple is an output column. Your function doesn't output a tuple. If you change the return line to `return (ratings_for_common_movies,)` then it outputs a tuple and will work.
2. You can't add columns to polars dataframes with square bracket notation. The only thing that can be on the left side of the `=` is a df, never `df['new_column']=<something>`. If you're using an old version that does allow it then you shouldn't, in part, because new versions don't allow it. That means you have to do something like `df.with_columns(new_column=<some_expression>)`

In the case adding a column to an existing df while using `map_rows` you can use `hstack` like:

```
df=df.hstack(df.map_rows(get_common_movie_ratings)).rename({'column_0':'common_movie_ratings'})
```

The above is really an anti-pattern as using any of the `map_rows`, `map_elements`, etc when a native approach could work will be slower and less efficient. Scroll to the bottom for a `map_elements` approach.

### Native solution preamble

If we assume the lists are always 3 long then you could do this...

```
# this is the length of the user_movies lists
n_count=3

df.with_columns(
    # first gather the items from user_movies based on (yet to be created) 
    # indices list 
    pl.col('user_movies').list.gather(
        # use walrus operator to create new list which is the indices where 
        # user_movies are in common_movies this works by looping through 
        # each element and checking if it's in common_movies. When it is in common_movies
        # then it stores its place in the loop n variable. The n_count is the list size
        (indices:=pl.concat_list(
            pl.when(
                pl.col('user_movies').list.get(n).is_in(pl.col('common_movies'))
            )
            .then(pl.lit(n))
            for n in range(n_count)
        ).list.drop_nulls())
    ),
    # use the same indicies list to gather the corresponding elements from user_ratings
    pl.col('user_ratings').list.gather(indices)
)
```

Note that we're generating the indices list by looping through a range from 0 to the length of the list as `n` and when the item associated the `n`th position of `user_movies` is in `common_movies` then that `n` is put in the indices list. There is unfortunately not a `.index` like method in polars for `list` type columns so, without exploding the lists, this is the best way I can think of to create that indices list.

### Native solution answer

Polars itself can't recursively set `n_count` so we need to do it manually. By using lazy evaluation this is faster than other approaches as it can compute each `n_count` case in parallel.

```
(
    pl.concat([ # this is a list comprehension
        # From here to the "for n_count..." line is the same as the previous code
        # snippet except that, here, it's called inner_df and it's being 
        # made into a lazy frame 
        inner_df.lazy().with_columns(
        pl.col('user_movies').list.gather(
            (indices:=pl.concat_list(
                pl.when(
                    pl.col('user_movies').list.get(n).is_in(pl.col('common_movies'))
                )
                .then(pl.lit(n))
                for n in range(n_count)
            ).list.drop_nulls())
        ),
        pl.col('user_ratings').list.gather(indices)
    )
    # this is the iterating part of the list comprehension
    # it takes the original df, creates a column which is
    # a row index, then it creates a column which is the
    # length of the list, it then partitions up the df into
    # multiple dfs where each of the inner_dfs only has rows
    # where the list length is the same. By using as_dict=True
    # and .items(), it gives a convenient way to unpack the
    # n_count (length of the list) and the inner_df  
    for n_count, inner_df in (
        df
        .with_row_count('i') # original row position
        .with_columns(n_count=pl.col('user_movies').list.len())
        .partition_by('n_count', as_dict=True, include_key=False)
        .items())
    ])
    .sort('i') # sort by original row position
    .drop('i') # drop the row position column
    .collect() # run all of the queries in parallel
    )
shape: (5, 3)
┌───────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┐
│ user_movies   ┆ user_ratings ┆ common_movies │
│ ---           ┆ ---          ┆ ---           │
│ list[i64]     ┆ list[f64]    ┆ list[i64]     │
╞═══════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ [7064, 7153]  ┆ [5.0, 5.0]   ┆ [7064, 7153]  │
│ [7]           ┆ [2.0]        ┆ [7]           │
│ [110, 3927]   ┆ [4.0, 3.0]   ┆ [110, 3927]   │
│ [2]           ┆ [3.5]        ┆ [2]           │
│ [260, 195627] ┆ [1.0, 0.5]   ┆ [260, 195627] │
└───────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┘
```

By converting to `lazy` in the first part of the `concat` it allows for each frame to be calculated in parallel where each frame is a subset based on the length of the list. It also allows for the `indices` to become a CSER which means it only calculates it once even though there are 2 references to it.

Incidentally, for less code but more processing/time, you could simply set `n_counts` in the preamble section to `n_count=df.select(n_count=pl.col('user_movies').list.len().max()).item()` and then just run the rest of what's in that section. That approach will be much slower than this one as, for every row it iterates through elements up to the max list length which adds unnecessary checks. It also doesn't get the same parallelism. In other words, it's doing more work with fewer CPU cores working on it.

### Benchmarks

Fake data creation

```
n=10_000_000
df = (
    pl.DataFrame({
        'user':np.random.randint(1,int(n/10),size=n),
        'user_movies':np.random.randint(1,50,n),
        'user_ratings':np.random.uniform(1,5, n),
        'keep':np.random.randint(1,100,n)
    })
    .group_by('user')
    .agg(
        pl.col('user_movies'),
        pl.col('user_ratings').round(1),
        common_movies=pl.col('user_movies').filter(pl.col('keep')>75)
        )
    .filter(pl.col('common_movies').list.len()>0)
    .drop('user')
    )
print(df.head(10))
shape: (5, 3)
┌────────────────┬───────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ user_movies    ┆ user_ratings      ┆ common_movies │
│ ---            ┆ ---               ┆ ---           │
│ list[i64]      ┆ list[f64]         ┆ list[i64]     │
╞════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═══════════════╡
│ [23, 35, … 22] ┆ [3.4, 1.6, … 4.0] ┆ [35]          │
│ [30, 18, … 26] ┆ [4.9, 1.9, … 2.3] ┆ [10]          │
│ [25, 19, … 29] ┆ [1.7, 1.7, … 1.1] ┆ [18, 40, 38]  │
│ [31, 15, … 42] ┆ [2.9, 1.8, … 4.3] ┆ [31, 4, … 42] │
│ [36, 16, … 49] ┆ [1.0, 2.0, … 4.2] ┆ [36]          │
└────────────────┴───────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

My method (16 threads): 1.92 s ± 195 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

My method (8 threads): 2.31 s ± 175 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

My method (4 threads): 3.14 s ± 221 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

@jqurious: 2.73 s ± 130 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

`map_rows`: 9.12 s ± 195 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Preamble with big n_count: 9.77 s ± 1.61 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

My method and the map_rows each use about 1 GB of RAM but the explody one is closer to 3 GB.

##### struct and map_elements

Instead of using `map_rows` which is, imo, really clunky, you can instead use [`map_elements`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_elements.html#polars.Expr.map_elements). It has its own clunkiness as you often need to wrap your input in a struct but you can add columns more cleanly and you don't have to rely on column position.

For instance you can define your function and use it as follows:

```
def get_common_movie_ratings(row): #Each row is a tuple of arrays.
    common_movies = row['common_movies'] #the index of the tuple denotes the 3rd array, which represents the common_movies column.
    user_ratings = row['user_ratings']
    ratings_for_common_movies= [user_ratings[list(row['user_movies']).index(movie)] for movie in common_movies]
    return ratings_for_common_movies
df.with_columns(user_ratings=pl.struct(pl.all()).map_elements(get_common_movie_ratings))
```

What's happening here is that `map_elements` can only be invoked from a single column so if your custom function needs multiple inputs you can wrap them in a struct. The struct will get turned into a dict where the keys have the name of the columns. This approach doesn't have any inherent performance benefit relative to the `map_rows`, it's just, imo, better syntax.

### Lastly

As @jqurious mentioned in comments of his answer, this could almost certainly be streamlined in terms of both syntax and performance by incorporating this logic with the formation of these lists. In other words, you have step 1: ______ step 2: this question. While I can only guess at what's happening in step 1 it is very likely that combining the two steps would be a worthwhile endeavor.

Comment: First of all, let me thank you for your time and detailed answer. Your approach with ```map_elements()``` made the trick. Cool to know of this ```pl.struck``` method. Secondly, I want to know if the native code you wrote will result to the same output as the ```map_elements``` function. I am asking because I am not familiar with native polars and I would like to learn more by executing your native approach.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the same. I suppose I threw the kitchen sink into the native method as far as tricks go so it's not super readable.

Comment: Dean, could you please elaborate on the functionality after creating the ```inner_df``` in the native approach. You do a loop like ```for n_count, inner_df in```, What is ```n_count``` and why you have to compute it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Dean please check here https://stackoverflow.com/q/77567521/10623444

Answer (score 2):

**[Update]:** This approach uses ~30% less memory (but is slightly slower)

As mentioned in the comments though, if you can share an example of the starting datasets, it's likely this can be done in a much simpler fashion.

```py
(df.with_row_count()
   .with_columns(common_ratings = 
         pl.col("user_ratings").list.gather(
             pl.col("user_movies").flatten().is_in(pl.col("common_movies").flatten())
               .over("row_nr", mapping_strategy="join")
               .list.eval(pl.element().arg_true())
         )
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (5, 5)
┌────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ user_movies         ┆ user_ratings    ┆ common_movies ┆ common_ratings │
│ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---             ┆ ---           ┆ ---            │
│ u32    ┆ list[i64]           ┆ list[f64]       ┆ list[i64]     ┆ list[f64]      │
╞════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [7064, 7153, 78009] ┆ [5.0, 5.0, 5.0] ┆ [7064, 7153]  ┆ [5.0, 5.0]     │
│ 1      ┆ [6, 7, 1042]        ┆ [4.0, 2.0, 4.0] ┆ [7]           ┆ [2.0]          │
│ 2      ┆ [99, 110, 3927]     ┆ [4.0, 4.0, 3.0] ┆ [110, 3927]   ┆ [4.0, 3.0]     │
│ 3      ┆ [2, 11, 152081]     ┆ [3.5, 3.0, 4.0] ┆ [2]           ┆ [3.5]          │
│ 4      ┆ [260, 318, 195627]  ┆ [1.0, 4.5, 0.5] ┆ [260, 195627] ┆ [1.0, 0.5]     │
└────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┘
```

---

As for the performing the task you've described "natively": (i.e. without UDFs)

You essentially need to reshape your data.

```py
(df.with_row_count()
   .explode("user_movies", "user_ratings")
)
```

```py
shape: (15, 4)
┌────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ user_movies ┆ user_ratings ┆ common_movies       │
│ ---    ┆ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---                 │
│ u32    ┆ i64         ┆ f64          ┆ list[i64]           │
╞════════╪═════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 7064        ┆ 5.0          ┆ [7064, 7153]        │
│ 0      ┆ 7153        ┆ 5.0          ┆ [7064, 7153]        │
│ 0      ┆ 78009       ┆ 5.0          ┆ [7064, 7153]        │
│ 1      ┆ 6           ┆ 4.0          ┆ [7]                 │
│ …      ┆ …           ┆ …            ┆ …                   │
│ 3      ┆ 152081      ┆ 4.0          ┆ [2]                 │
│ 4      ┆ 260         ┆ 1.0          ┆ [260, 1291, 195627] │
│ 4      ┆ 318         ┆ 4.5          ┆ [260, 1291, 195627] │
│ 4      ┆ 195627      ┆ 0.5          ┆ [260, 1291, 195627] │
└────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

You can then use Polars functionality e.g. `.filter()` + `.is_in()` to keep the matching rows.

```py
(df.with_row_count()
   .explode("user_movies", "user_ratings")
   .filter(pl.col("user_movies").is_in("common_movies"))
   .group_by("row_nr", maintain_order=True)
   .agg("user_movies", "user_ratings")
)
```

```py
shape: (5, 3)
┌────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ user_movies   ┆ user_ratings │
│ ---    ┆ ---           ┆ ---          │
│ u32    ┆ list[i64]     ┆ list[f64]    │
╞════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [7064, 7153]  ┆ [5.0, 5.0]   │
│ 1      ┆ [7]           ┆ [2.0]        │
│ 2      ┆ [110, 3927]   ┆ [4.0, 3.0]   │
│ 3      ┆ [2]           ┆ [3.5]        │
│ 4      ┆ [260, 195627] ┆ [1.0, 0.5]   │
└────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. My only problem with your approach is that I have a really huge DF (~ 2million rows). So exploding the 254,000 grouped rows to the original 2mllion rows will cause memory errors.

Comment: @NikSp Did you try using LazyFrames?

Comment: @NikSp Also, are you saying the data is originally ungrouped and the example you've shown is the result of a `.group_by()`? If so, it's probably simpler to start with the original ungrouped data as having everything as lists like this is somewhat awkward.

Comment: ```LazyFrames``` I didn't try them. As for the second question the dataset is original a 2million rows dataframe, after group by(s) I transformed it to a 254,000 rows (each row is a userId). So my operations should be performed on that 254,000 rows df and not the original one. This is because the column "common_movies" is not part of the initial df too. It's also a ```map_elements()``` new column.

Comment: @NikSp Alrightly. If you're up to it, I think the best thing would be simply to start a new question with the 2 initial datasets. It will be much simpler to show how to do this natively in Polars without `.map_elements` so you don't end up with everything as lists the way they currently are.

Comment: Ok I will open a new question. For the record, I want to compute cosine similarity between users. And the cosine function as I have built it takes two arrays as input. That's why user_ratings of common_movies must be an array per user. I will elaborate on my new question about this.

Comment: For memory mitigation you can do something like `pl.concat([df[slice].<above> for slice in slices])`

Comment: @jqurious please check here https://stackoverflow.com/q/77567521/10623444