# Optimize computation of similarity scores by executing native polars command instead of UDF functions

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, python-polars

**Disclaimer (1):** This question is supportive to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77541498/10623444). After a request from two users to elaborate on my case.

**Disclaimer (2) - added 29/11:** I have seen two solutions so far (proposed in this SO and the supportive one), that utilize the `explode()` functionality. Based on some benchmarks I did on the whole (~3m rows data) the RAM literally *explodes*, thus I will test the function on a sample of the dataset and if it works I will accept the solutions of `explode()` method for those who might experiment on smaller tables.

The input dataset (~3m rows) is the `ratings.csv` from the ml-latest dataset of 80_000 IMDb movies and respective ratings from 330_000 users (you may download the CSV file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C5AkLrXjUu-BlhgzZdIIqZ-paavDuYkt/view?usp=sharing) - 891mb).

I load the dataset using `polars` like `movie_ratings = pl.read_csv(os.path.join(application_path + data_directory, "ratings.csv"))`, `application_path` and `data_directory` is a parent path on my local server.

Having read the dataset my goal is to generate the cosine similarity of a user between all the other users. To do so, first I have to transform the ratings table (~3m rows) to a table with 1 row per user. Thus, I run the following query

```py
## 1st computation bottleneck using UDF functions (2.5minutes for 250_000 rows)
users_metadata = movie_ratings.filter(
        (pl.col("userId") != input_id) #input_id is a random userId. I prefer to make my tests using userId '1' so input_id=1 in this case.
    ).group_by("userId")\
        .agg(
            pl.col("movieId").unique().alias("user_movies"),
            pl.col("rating").alias("user_ratings")
        )\
        .with_columns(
            pl.col("user_movies").map_elements(
                lambda row: sorted( list(set(row).intersection(set(user_rated_movies))) ), return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Int64)
            ).alias("common_movies")
        )\
        .with_columns(
            pl.col("common_movies").map_elements(
                lambda row: len(row), return_dtype=pl.Int64
            ).alias("common_movies_frequency")
        )
similar_users = (
    users_metadata.filter(
       (pl.col("common_movies_frequency").le(len(user_rated_movies))) &
       (pl.col("common_movies_frequency").gt(0)) # we don't want the users that don't have seen any movies from the ones seen/rated by the target user.
    )
    .sort("common_movies_frequency", descending=True)
)

## 2nd computation bottleneck using UDF functions
similar_users = (
    similar_users.with_columns(
        pl.struct(pl.all()).map_elements(
            get_common_movie_ratings, #asked on StackOverflow
            return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Float64),
            strategy="threading"
        ).alias("common_movie_ratings")
    ).with_columns(
        pl.struct(["common_movies"]).map_elements(
            lambda row: get_target_movie_ratings(row, user_rated_movies, user_ratings),
            return_dtype=pl.List(pl.Float64),
            strategy="threading"
        ).alias("target_user_common_movie_ratings")
    ).with_columns(
        pl.struct(["common_movie_ratings","target_user_common_movie_ratings"]).map_elements(
             lambda row: compute_cosine(row),
             return_dtype=pl.Float64,
             strategy="threading"
        ).alias("similarity_score")
    )
)
```

The code snippet above groups the table by userId and computes some important metadata about them. Specifically,

- user_movies, user_ratings per user
- common_movies = intersection of the movies seen by the user that are the same as seen by the input_id user (thus user 1). Movies seen by the user 1 are basically `user_rated_movies = movie_ratings.filter(pl.col("userId") == input_id).select("movieId").to_numpy().ravel()`
- common_movies_frequency = The length of the column`common_movies` per user. NOT a fixed length per user.
- common_movie_ratings = The result of the function I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77541498/10623444)
- target_user_common_movie_ratings = The ratings of the target user (user1) that match the indexes of the common movies with each user.
- similarity_score = The cosine similarity score.

Screenshot of the table (don't give attention to column `potential recommendations`)
[image]

Finally, I filter the table `users_metadata` by all the users with less than or equal common_movies_frequency to the 62 (`len(user_rated_movies)`) movies seen by user1. Those are a total of 250_000 users.

This table is the input dataframe for the UDF function I asked in this question. Using this dataframe (~250_000 users) I want to calculate the cosine similarity of each user with user 1. To do so, I want to compare their rating similarity. So on the movies commonly rated by each user, compute the cosine similarity among two arrays of ratings.

Below are the three UDF functions I use to support my functionality.

```py
def get_common_movie_ratings(row) -> pl.List(pl.Float64):
    common_movies = row['common_movies']
    user_ratings = row['user_ratings']
    ratings_for_common_movies = [user_ratings[list(row['user_movies']).index(movie)] for movie in common_movies]
    return ratings_for_common_movies

def get_target_movie_ratings(row, target_user_movies:np.ndarray, target_user_ratings:np.ndarray) -> pl.List(pl.Float64):
    common_movies = row['common_movies']
    target_user_common_ratings = [target_user_ratings[list(target_user_movies).index(movie)] for movie in common_movies]
    return target_user_common_ratings

def compute_cosine(row)->pl.Float64:
    array1 = row["common_movie_ratings"]
    array2 = row["target_user_common_movie_ratings"]
    magnitude1 = norm(array1)
    magnitude2 = norm(array2)
    if magnitude1 != 0 or magnitude2 != 0: #avoid division with 0 norms/magnitudes
        score: float = np.dot(array1, array2) / (norm(array1) * norm(array2))
    else:
        score: float = 0.0
    return score
```

> Benchmarks

- Total execution time for 1 user is ~4 minutes. If I have to compute this over an iteration per user (1 dataframe per user) that will be approximately4 minutess * 330_000 users.
- 3-5Gb of RAM while computing the polars df for 1 user.

The main question is how can I transform those 3 UDF functions into native polars commands.

#### logs from a custom logger I made

> 2023-11-29 13:40:24 - INFO - Computed potential similar user metadata for 254188 users in: 0:02:15.586497

> 2023-11-29 13:40:51 - INFO - Computed similarity scores for 194943 users in: 0:00:27.472388

We can conclude that the main bottleneck of the code is when creating the `user_metadata` table.

Comment: Where's `user_rated_movies`'s definition?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor `user_rated_movies = movie_ratings.filter(pl.col("userId") == input_id).select("movieId").to_numpy().ravel()` (it's listed in one of the subpoints after the first codeblock). `movie_ratings` is the [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C5AkLrXjUu-BlhgzZdIIqZ-paavDuYkt/view?usp=sharing) (warning: it's `891mb`)

Comment: Here's a thing https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/speed-up-cosine-similarity-computations-in-python-using-numba-c04bc0741750

Comment: Nice @DeanMacGregor! Didn't know of ```Numba```. Cosine is one of the four similarity functions I use, but in any case, they can all be adjusted to Numba. Will keep this in mind.

Comment: RE: explode/memory - this type of behaviour in Polars is considered a "bug" (most recent example: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12659) Polars is supposed to be able to do this sort of thing. Appreciate all the effort/detail in your question - will try to post a full answer.

Comment: Just as an example: The `users_metadata` step takes `~65s` on this current machine and `movie_ratings.filter((pl.col("userId") != 1) & (pl.col("movieId").is_in(pl.col("movieId").filter(pl.col("userId") == 1))))` takes `~2s` (which also gives you the common_rating)

Comment: @jqurious should I use ```explode()```? since my initial table (before ```group_by``` has already ~3 millions rows. My approach has this major bottleneck of grouping and creating ```pl.Lists```.

Comment: @jqurious I am starting to get curious about the ```user_metadata``` table because it take approximately 2.30minutes to compute for 250_000 users (after ```group_by()``` by userId. The ```user_metadata``` table is one step before computing the similarity scores.

Comment: Essentially all of the `.map_elements` calls can go. I don't think `.explode()` will be needed anymore as you can find the intersecting/common ratings before any grouping. Just finishing up an example now.

Comment: There may be a better strategy to do this for all users at the same time. But I've added an initial answer which should be equivlant to all the steps shown except for `compute_cosine` (As @Wayoshi showed, that can be done with expressions.) For larger data like this, the final solution will probably use LazyFrames instead.

Comment: @jqurious I have added also some benchmarks from the current solution using a logger object. As you can see I print in the console the time execution of those UDF commands. And the clear bottleneck is found in the ```user_metadata``` table and not in the computation of the similarity score.

Comment: Yes, it's sending all of the data to Python: `sorted( list(set(row).intersection` - there is also `pl.col("common_movies").map_elements(lambda row: len(row)` which should be written as `pl.col("common_movies").list.len()` - Basically, `.map_elements` should "never" be used: **Warning:** *"This method is much slower than the native expressions API. Only use it if you cannot implement your logic otherwise."*

Comment: Just taking a closer look at the full dataset: there are `330,975` unique userIds. I think this is essentially a "graph" / "connected nodes" type problem (SQL is usually better for these). If you tried to generate all the comparisons e.g. with a cross join - it would be over 100 billion rows (50 billion without duplicates) which you cannot even do unless you use `polars-u64-idx`. So while the initial input is not "big data", the "search space" for the actual task is enormous. (This may help explain why you're running into memory issues with some of the "regular" techniques being suggested.)

Comment: @jqurious Indeed, because I want to apply the user-user recommendation algorithm for all the users. To do so, each user should be compared to all the other users. Resulting to a really huge final table. However, although this is a challenging issue, I won't address it at the moment. This is why looping over each user is much more memory efficient but longer to complete task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CSV

- `pl.read_csv` loads everything into memory.
- [`pl.scan_csv()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html) returns a LazyFrame instead.

#### Parquet

- faster to read/write
- `pl.scan_csv("imdb.csv").sink_parquet("imdb.parquet")`
- imdb.csv = 891mb / imdb.parquet = 202mb

#### Example:

In the hopes of making things simpler for replicating results, I've filtered the dataset `pl.col("userId").is_between(1, 3)` and removed the `timestamp` column:

```py
movie_ratings = pl.read_csv(
    b'userId,movieId,rating\n1,1,4.0\n1,110,4.0\n1,158,4.0\n1,260,4.5\n1,356,5.0\n1,381,3.5\n1,596,4.0\n1,1036,5.0\n1,1049,'
    b'3.0\n1,1066,4.0\n1,1196,3.5\n1,1200,3.5\n1,1210,4.5\n1,1214,4.0\n1,1291,5.0\n1,1293,2.0\n1,1376,3.0\n1,1396,3.0\n1,153'
    b'7,4.0\n1,1909,3.0\n1,1959,4.0\n1,1960,4.0\n1,2028,5.0\n1,2085,3.5\n1,2116,4.0\n1,2336,3.5\n1,2571,2.5\n1,2671,4.0\n1,2'
    b'762,5.0\n1,2804,3.0\n1,2908,4.0\n1,3363,3.0\n1,3578,5.0\n1,4246,4.0\n1,4306,4.0\n1,4699,3.5\n1,4886,5.0\n1,4896,4.0\n1'
    b',4993,4.0\n1,4995,5.0\n1,5952,4.5\n1,6539,4.0\n1,7064,3.5\n1,7122,4.0\n1,7139,3.0\n1,7153,5.0\n1,7162,4.0\n1,7366,3.5'
    b'\n1,7706,3.5\n1,8132,5.0\n1,8533,5.0\n1,8644,3.5\n1,8961,4.5\n1,8969,4.0\n1,8981,3.5\n1,33166,5.0\n1,33794,3.0\n1,40629'
    b',4.5\n1,49647,5.0\n1,52458,5.0\n1,53996,5.0\n1,54259,4.0\n2,1,5.0\n2,2,3.0\n2,6,4.0\n2,10,3.0\n2,11,3.0\n2,17,5.0\n2,1'
    b'9,3.0\n2,21,5.0\n2,25,3.0\n2,31,3.0\n2,34,5.0\n2,36,5.0\n2,39,3.0\n2,47,5.0\n2,48,2.0\n2,50,4.0\n2,52,3.0\n2,58,3.0\n2'
    b',95,2.0\n2,110,5.0\n2,111,3.0\n2,141,5.0\n2,150,5.0\n2,151,5.0\n2,153,3.0\n2,158,3.0\n2,160,1.0\n2,161,3.0\n2,165,4.0'
    b'\n2,168,3.0\n2,172,2.0\n2,173,2.0\n2,185,3.0\n2,186,3.0\n2,204,3.0\n2,208,3.0\n2,224,3.0\n2,225,3.0\n2,231,4.0\n2,235,3'
    b'.0\n2,236,2.0\n2,252,3.0\n2,253,2.0\n2,256,3.0\n2,261,4.0\n2,265,2.0\n2,266,4.0\n2,282,1.0\n2,288,1.0\n2,292,3.0\n2,29'
    b'3,3.0\n2,296,5.0\n2,300,4.0\n2,315,3.0\n2,317,3.0\n2,318,5.0\n2,333,3.0\n2,337,3.0\n2,339,5.0\n2,344,3.0\n2,349,4.0\n2'
    b',350,3.0\n2,356,5.0\n2,357,5.0\n2,364,4.0\n2,367,4.0\n2,377,4.0\n2,380,4.0\n2,420,2.0\n2,432,3.0\n2,434,4.0\n2,440,3.0'
    b'\n2,442,3.0\n2,454,3.0\n2,457,5.0\n2,480,3.0\n2,500,4.0\n2,509,3.0\n2,527,5.0\n2,539,5.0\n2,553,3.0\n2,586,4.0\n2,587,'
    b'4.0\n2,588,4.0\n2,589,4.0\n2,590,5.0\n2,592,3.0\n2,593,5.0\n2,595,4.0\n2,597,5.0\n2,786,4.0\n3,296,5.0\n3,318,5.0\n3,8'
    b'58,5.0\n3,2959,5.0\n3,3114,5.0\n3,3751,5.0\n3,4886,5.0\n3,6377,5.0\n3,8961,5.0\n3,60069,5.0\n3,68954,5.0\n3,69844,5.0'
    b'\n3,74458,5.0\n3,76093,5.0\n3,79132,5.0\n3,81834,5.0\n3,88125,5.0\n3,99114,5.0\n3,109487,5.0\n3,112556,5.0\n3,115617,5.'
    b'0\n3,115713,4.0\n3,116797,5.0\n3,119145,5.0\n3,134853,5.0\n3,152081,5.0\n3,176101,5.0\n3,177765,5.0\n3,185029,5.0\n3,1'
    b'87593,3.0\n'
)
```

We will assume `input_id == 1`

One possible approach for gathering all the needed information:

```py
# Finding the intersection first seems to use ~35% less RAM
# than the previous join / anti-join approach
intersection = (
   movie_ratings
    .filter(
       (pl.col("userId") == 1)
       | 
       ((pl.col("userId") != 1) &
        (pl.col("movieId").is_in(pl.col("movieId").filter(pl.col("userId") == 1))))
    )
)

(intersection.filter(pl.col("userId") == 1)
  .join(
     intersection.filter(pl.col("userId") != 1),
     on = "movieId"
  )
  .group_by(pl.col("userId_right").alias("other_user"))
  .agg(
     target_user = pl.first("userId"),
     common_movies = "movieId",
     common_movies_frequency = pl.count(),
     target_user_ratings = "rating",
     other_user_ratings = "rating_right",
  )
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 6)
┌────────────┬─────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ other_user ┆ target_user ┆ common_movies      ┆ common_movies_frequency ┆ target_user_ratings  ┆ other_user_ratings   │
│ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---                ┆ ---                     ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  │
│ i64        ┆ i64         ┆ list[i64]          ┆ u32                     ┆ list[f64]            ┆ list[f64]            │
╞════════════╪═════════════╪════════════════════╪═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 3          ┆ 1           ┆ [4886, 8961]       ┆ 2                       ┆ [5.0, 4.5]           ┆ [5.0, 5.0]           │
│ 2          ┆ 1           ┆ [1, 110, 158, 356] ┆ 4                       ┆ [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0] ┆ [5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 5.0] │
└────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

#### Lazy API

There may be a better strategy to parallelize the work, but a baseline attempt could simply loop through each userID

```py
movie_ratings = pl.scan_parquet("imdb.parquet")

user_ids = movie_ratings.select(pl.col("userId").unique()).collect().to_series()

for user_id in user_ids:
    result = (
        movie_ratings
            .filter(pl.col("userId") == user_id)
            ...
    )
    print(result.collect())
```

#### DuckDB

I was curious, so decided to check [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python/overview.html) for a comparison.

```py
import duckdb

duckdb.sql("""
with 
   db as (from movie_ratings)
from 
   db target, db other
select 
   target.userId        target_user,
   other.userId         other_user,
   list(other.movieId)  common_movies,
   count(other.movieId) common_movies_frequency,
   list(target.rating)  target_user_ratings,
   list(other.rating)   other_user_ratings,
where 
   target_user = 1 and other_user != 1 and target.movieId = other.movieId
group by 
   target_user, other_user
""").pl()
```

```py
shape: (2, 6)
┌─────────────┬────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ target_user ┆ other_user ┆ common_movies      ┆ common_movies_frequency ┆ target_user_ratings  ┆ other_user_ratings   │
│ ---         ┆ ---        ┆ ---                ┆ ---                     ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  │
│ i64         ┆ i64        ┆ list[i64]          ┆ i64                     ┆ list[f64]            ┆ list[f64]            │
╞═════════════╪════════════╪════════════════════╪═════════════════════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 1           ┆ 3          ┆ [4886, 8961]       ┆ 2                       ┆ [5.0, 4.5]           ┆ [5.0, 5.0]           │
│ 1           ┆ 2          ┆ [1, 110, 356, 158] ┆ 4                       ┆ [4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0] ┆ [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0] │
└─────────────┴────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

#### RAM Usage

Running both examples against the full dataset (runtime is basically the same) I get:

```py
import rich.filesize

print("duckdb:", rich.filesize.decimal(223232000))
print("polars:", rich.filesize.decimal(1772072960))
```

```
duckdb: 223.2 MB
polars: 1.8 GB
```

So it seems there is potential room for improvement on the Polars side.

Comment: Well documented answer. Tested, on one user. Improved computation time from 50 second to 1 second. Thanks a lot jqurious! I will look more into your solution and in polars when I have time.

Comment: jqurious can you have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593997/efficiently-compute-item-colaborating-filtering-similarity-using-numba-polars-a pls :)

Comment: @NikSp I did have a look but found it rather difficult to follow what `item_compute_similarity_scoring_V2` is actually comparing against. I think it would be similar to what is discussed here, the `.map_elements` would be replaced with filter/join. Will take another look tomorrow.

Comment: jqurious basically, I have two dataframes/tables. One df with the ```other_movies``` not seen by user. And a second dataframe with the movies seen by him. The first df has 80k rows while the second has 62 (if we take the example of user 1). Those two dataframes cannot be joined on any key, because they have different movies. Inside the function ```item_compute_similarity_scoring_V2``` I iterate over each row of df_2 with each movie from df_1. So for every ```other_movie``` I do 62 iterations. For each iteration, I compute the similarity score of each pair.

Comment: @NikSp Yeah, but inside `item_ratings` there is a `keep only common users` part. That "intersection" should be able to be expressed in terms of some joins/filters instead of `map_elements` + `for loop`.

Comment: ```item_ratings``` keeps only the common users as you type. So you are saying that instead of doing ```df_2.iter_rows()``` and ```map_elements()``` to use joins/filters. But how can I make the comparison between ```other_movies``` and each of the 62 movies from df2. If you see my example, the first row movie ```249408``` should be compared only with the ratings of user ```163085``` for all the 62 rows/movies in the second dataframe. The next iteration/row of movie ```167664``` has been rated by three users. The ratings of those three users only for the 62 movies should be selected, etc..

Comment: Jqurious also letting you know that my initial approach (you may find it here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bINpbYGRkopBgAsQprBi58YZnEUNpLMl/view?usp=sharing)..Used join/filter operations but took me 9 min to complete, while now I get it done under 2 min.

Comment: @NikSp Yes, defining the rules for the "intersection only comparisons" was the part I was struggling with. RE: code - https://gist.github.com/cmdlineluser/0ef6b8aa03ca0c1370e4b4d0b022df82 may help. Currently, you have a mix of numpy/polars/for-loops. For a meaningful benchmark, you would want to start with a "fully native Polars solution" i.e. no `to_numpy` / no `map_elements`, etc.

Comment: @NikSp `target_items_metadata.filter(pl.lit(163085).is_in("users_seen_movie"))` is probably a better example. But there should be a way to combine everything together all at once.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach I came up with, using a random `df` 1/100th the size of the given dataset:

```py
np.random.seed(1)

n = 30_000

movie_ratings_raw = pl.DataFrame({
    'userId' : np.random.randint(3_000, size=n),
    'movieId' : np.random.randint(800, size=n),
    'userRating' : np.random.randint(1, 11, size=n)
})

movie_ratings = movie_ratings_raw.group_by('userId', 'movieId').agg(
    pl.col('userRating').first()
)

movie_ratings = movie_ratings.group_by('userId').all()
```

(I think userId & movieId should be unique in the actual dataset?)

Then:

```py
user_simliarities = {}

for (uid, mid, ur) in movie_ratings.iter_rows())
    mr = movie_ratings_raw.filter(pl.col('userId') != uid)
    cosines = (
        mr.with_columns(compare_movieId=mid, compare_rating=ur)
        .explode('compare_movieId', 'compare_rating')
        .filter(pl.col('movieId') == pl.col('compare_movieId'))
        .with_columns(
            userRatingSquared=pl.col('userRating') ** 2,
            compareRatingSquared=pl.col('compare_rating') ** 2,
        )
        .group_by('userId')
        .agg(
            similarity_score=pl.when(pl.count() == 1)
            .then(1)
            .otherwise(
                pl.col('userRating').dot(pl.col('compare_rating'))
                / (
                    (pl.col('userRatingSquared').sum().sqrt())
                    * (pl.col('compareRatingSquared').sum().sqrt())
                )
            )
        )
    )

    user_simliarities[uid] = (
        mr.select('userId').join(cosines, 'userId', 'outer').fill_null(0)
    )
```

This will put a `2999x2` dataframe per userId into the final dictionary. These can all be concatenated with an additional `with_column(pl.lit(key_of_dict).alias('user2')` or some such if one big final `df` is wanted.

Note how:

- two columns of literals of the movieIds and user_ratings of a given user are added to the intermediate dataframe `mr`, very simple syntax here
- `list_intersection` is avoided simply by doing an `explode` to generate all combinations of movie/ratings between two users, and a `filter` on all rows that have matching `movieId`s
- I precompute the squares of the ratings because `list.eval` is considered slow
- When there's just one matching movie, we know the result will be 1, so short-circuit and save some calculations there
- All the non-matching users are added in at the end with a `join` and `fill_null`

Generating all `3000` of these `2999x2` `dfs` took my machine 62 seconds - not really sure how feasible this will be at full size (and I'm not sure a reasonable solution exists for getting every userId combo, especially at that size), but at least it is all native polars!

Comment: I have a question. Why you group the data by ```userId``` and ```movieId``` and then ```explode()``` the dataframe again? In essence that you already have ~3million rows , loading it in memory, then use ```group_by``` and then again ```explode()``` to reload data in RAM. This is totally a way to run out of RAM. Why don't you apply the polars commands on the initial df of ~3million rows before ```group_by```?

Comment: Was trying a few different ways under the hood, but you're definitely right on that. I edited the answer to just use `movie_ratings_raw` to skip that step.

Answer (score 4):

You can use numba to compile the similarity function into a ufunc which can be placed directly in an expression without using a call to `map_*`. Additionally, you can self join the df to itself to do all of the list intersection stuff. You can use pyarrow's parquet writer in order to write chunks of results to an open file without materializing it all at once.

There are a bunch of commented out lines that I think are actually unnecessary given the parquet writer, which is why they're commented out. Essentially they just save bits to files to try to lessen the memory requirement.

I played around with keeping the main df as a `scan_parquet` lazyframe but it slows it down a good bit since it constantly has to read the file and, on my computer, that individual file isn't too big for memory. It's the big join that chews up a lot of memory.

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
from datetime import datetime
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow as pa

# pl.read_csv(
#     "./ratings.csv"
# ).write_parquet('./ratings.parquet', statistics=True)

df = pl.read_parquet("./ratings.parquet")


@nb.guvectorize([(nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:], nb.float64[:])], "(n),(n)->(n)")
def similarity(u, v, res):
    uv = 0
    uu = 0
    vv = 0
    for i in range(u.shape[0]):
        uv += u[i] * v[i]
        uu += u[i] * u[i]
        vv += v[i] * v[i]
    res[0] = 1
    if uu != 0 and vv != 0:
        res[0] = uv / np.sqrt(uu * vv)


arrow_schema = pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field("userId", pa.int32()),
        pa.field("user_movies", pa.large_list(pa.int64())),
        pa.field("user_ratings", pa.large_list(pa.float64())),
        pa.field("common_movies", pa.large_list(pa.int64())),
        pa.field("common_movie_ratings", pa.large_list(pa.float64())),
        pa.field("target_user_common_movie_ratings", pa.large_list(pa.float64())),
        pa.field("similarity_score", pa.float64()),
    ]
)


with pq.ParquetWriter("allresults.parquet", arrow_schema, compression="zstd") as writer:
    for userid in df["userId"].unique():
        print(f"{datetime.now()}: {userid}")
        df_split = (
            df.drop("timestamp")
            .with_columns(is_id=pl.col("userId") == userid)
            .partition_by("is_id", as_dict=True, include_key=False)
        )
        # left_file=NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        # df_split[True].write_parquet(left_file.name)
        # right_file=NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        # df_split[False].write_parquet(right_file.name)
        # left = pl.scan_parquet(left_file.name)
        # right = pl.scan_parquet(right_file.name)
        left = df_split[True].lazy()
        right = df_split[False].lazy()
        joined = left.join(right, on="movieId")
        # joined_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        # print('sinking')
        # joined.sink_parquet(joined_file.name)
        # joined=pl.scan_parquet(joined_file.name)
        res = (
            joined.select(
                userId=pl.lit(userid),
                user_movies=df_split[True]["movieId"].implode(),
                user_ratings=df_split[True]["rating"].implode(),
                common_movies=pl.col("movieId").implode(),
                common_movie_ratings=pl.col("rating_right").implode(),
                target_user_common_movie_ratings=pl.col("rating").implode(),
                similarity_score = similarity(
                    pl.col("rating"), pl.col("rating_right")
                ).first(),
            )
            .collect()
            .to_arrow()
        )
        writer.write_table(res)
        print(f"{datetime.now()}: done with {userid}")
```

I verified that, at least for `userid==1` that the similarity score matches the result from `compute_cosine`. I let it run for about 11 minutes and in that time it did 584 users. It would go even faster if it weren't writing the results to disk after each user. There's probably an opportunity to set it up such that it only writes to disk after it's accumulated a few users worth of results but defining how many users that should be is system/memory dependent.

Comment: A good to-know solution. Based on the benchmarks I have uploaded, the computation of similarity score using a UDF function optimized with ```Numba``` is taking 27 seconds for user1. Thus, the overall bottleneck is mainly in the process of transforming the dataset into a format for a single user that will help compute the similarity scores. Thanks!

Comment: @NikSp the code above does everything to reproduce your screen cap in the question at a rate of less than a second per user. Did it not run for you?

Comment: Dean, didn't had the chance to run it yet. I will do it during the weekend, cause I have to benchmark all the solutions. Will keep you post it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Dean MacGregor could you please have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/77593997/10623444 Thanks!