# Efficiently compute item colaborating filtering similarity using numba, polars and numpy

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, numba, python-polars

**Disclaimer** The question is part of a thread including those two SO questions ([q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77567521/10623444), [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77558612/10623444))

The data resemble movie ratings from the ratings.csv [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C5AkLrXjUu-BlhgzZdIIqZ-paavDuYkt/view?usp=sharing) (~891mb) of ml-latest dataset.

Once I read the csv file with `polars` library like:

```py
movie_ratings = pl.read_csv(os.path.join(application_path + data_directory, "ratings.csv"))
```

*Let's assume we want to compute the similarity between movies seen by user=1 (so for example 62 movies) with the rest of the movies in the dataset. FYI, the dataset has ~83,000 movies so for each other_movie (82,938) compute a similarity with each movie seen by user 1 (62 movies). The complexity is 62x82938 (iterations).*

For this example the benchmarks reported are only for 400/82,938 `other_movies`

To do so, I create two `polars` dataframes. One dataframe with the `other_movies` (~82,938 row) and a second dataframe with only the movies seen by the user (62 rows).

```py
user_ratings = movie_ratings.filter(pl.col("userId")==input_id) #input_id = 1 (data related to user 1)
user_rated_movies = list(user_ratings.select(pl.col("movieId")).to_numpy().ravel()) #movies seen by user1
potential_movies_to_recommend = list(
    movie_ratings.select("movieId").filter( ~(pl.col("movieId").is_in(user_rated_movies)) ).unique().sort("movieId").to_numpy().ravel()
)

items_metadata = (
    movie_ratings.filter(
        ~pl.col("movieId").is_in(user_rated_movies) #& pl.col("movieId").is_in(potential_movie_recommendations[:total_unseen_movies])
    )
    .group_by("movieId").agg(
        users_seen_movie=pl.col("userId").unique(),
        user_ratings=pl.col("rating")
    )
)

target_items_metadata = (
    movie_ratings.filter(
        pl.col("movieId").is_in(user_rated_movies) #& pl.col("movieId").is_in(potential_movie_recommendations[:total_unseen_movies])
    ).group_by("movieId").agg(
        users_seen_movie=pl.col("userId").unique(),
        user_ratings=pl.col("rating")
    )
)
```

The result are two `polars` dataframes with rows(movies) and columns(users seen the movies & the ratings from each user).

[image]

The first dataframe contains only `other_movies` that we can potentially recommend to user1 seen he/she has not seen them.

The second dataframe contains only the movies seen by the user.

Next my approach is to iterate over each row of the first dataframe by applying a UDF function.

```py
item_metadata_similarity = (
    items_metadata.with_columns(
        similarity_score=pl.struct(pl.all()).map_elements(
            lambda row: item_compute_similarity_scoring_V2(row, similarity_metric, target_items_metadata),
            return_dtype=pl.List(pl.List(pl.Float64)),
            strategy="threading"
        )
    )
)
```

, where `item_compute_similarity_scoring_V2` is defined as:

```py
def item_compute_similarity_scoring_V2(
    row,
    target_movies_metadata:pl.DataFrame
):
    users_item1 = np.asarray(row["users_seen_movie"])
    ratings_item1 = np.asarray(row["user_ratings"])
    computed_similarity: list=[]
    for row2 in target_movies_metadata.iter_rows(named=True): #iter over each row from the second dataframe with the movies seen by the user.
        users_item2=np.asarray(row2["users_seen_movie"])
        ratings_item2=np.asarray(row2["user_ratings"])
        r1, r2 = item_ratings(users_item1, ratings_item1, users_item2, ratings_item2)
        if r1.shape[0] != 0 and r2.shape[0] != 0:
            similarity_score = compute_similarity_score(r1, r2)
            if similarity_score > 0.0: #filter out negative or zero similarity scores
                computed_similarity.append((row2["movieId"], similarity_score))
    most_similar_pairs = sorted(computed_similarity, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return most_similar_pairs
```

, `item_ratings` & `compute_similarity_score` defined as

```py
def item_ratings(u1:np.ndarray, r1:np.ndarray, u2:np.ndarray, r2:np.ndarray) -> (np.ndarray, np.ndarray):
    common_elements, indices1, indices2 = np.intersect1d(u1, u2, return_indices=True)
    sr1 = r1[indices1]
    sr2 = r2[indices2]
    assert len(sr1)==len(sr2), "ratings don't have same lengths"
    return sr1, sr2

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def compute_similarity_score(array1:np.ndarray, array2:np.ndarray) -> float:
    assert(array1.shape[0] == array2.shape[0])
    a1a2 = 0
    a1a1 = 0
    a2a2 = 0
    for i in range(array1.shape[0]):
        a1a2 += array1[i]*array2[i]
        a1a1 += array1[i]*array1[i]
        a2a2 += array2[i]*array2[i]
    cos_theta = 1.0
    if a1a1!=0 and a2a2!=0:
        cos_theta = float(a1a2/np.sqrt(a1a1*a2a2))
    return cos_theta
```

The function basically, iterates over each row of the second dataframe and for each row computes the similarity between `other_movie` and the movie seen by the user. Thus, for
400 movies we do 400*62 iterations, generating 62 similarity scores per `other_movie`.

The result from each computation is an array with schema `[[1, 0.20], [110, 0.34]]...` (length 62 pairs per `other_movie`)

[image]

> Benchmarks for 400 movies

1. INFO - Item-Item: Computed similarity scores for 400 movies in: 0:05:49.887032
2. ~2 minutes.
3. ~5gb of RAM used.

I would to identify how can I improve the computations by using native `polars` commands or exploiting the `numba` framework for parallelism.

##### Update - 2nd approach using `to_numpy()` operations without `iter_rows()` and `map_elements()`

```py
user_ratings = movie_ratings.filter(pl.col("userId")==input_id) #input_id = 1
user_rated_movies = user_ratings.select(pl.col("movieId")).to_numpy().ravel()
potential_movies_to_recommend = list(
    movie_ratings.select("movieId").filter( ~(pl.col("movieId").is_in(user_rated_movies)) ).unique().sort("movieId").to_numpy().ravel()
)
items_metadata = (
    movie_ratings.filter(
        ~pl.col("movieId").is_in(user_rated_movies)
    )
)
# print(items_metadata.head(5))
target_items_metadata = (
    movie_ratings.filter(
        pl.col("movieId").is_in(user_rated_movies)
    )
)
# print(target_items_metadata.head(5))
```

With this second approach `items_metadata` and `target_items_metadata` are two large polars tables.

Then my next step is to save both tables into `numpy.ndarrays` with the `to_numpy()` command.

```py
items_metadata_array = items_metadata.to_numpy()
target_items_metadata_array = target_items_metadata.to_numpy()
```

```py
computed_similarity_scores:dict = {}
for i, other_movie in enumerate(potential_movies_to_recommend[:400]): #take the first 400 unseen movies by user 1
    mask = items_metadata_array[:, 1] == other_movie
    other_movies_chunk = items_metadata_array[mask]
    u1 = other_movies_chunk[:,0].astype(np.int32)
    r1 = other_movies_chunk[:,2].astype(np.float32)
    computed_similarity: list=[]
    for i, user_movie in enumerate(user_rated_movies):
        print(user_movie)
        mask = target_items_metadata_array[:, 1] == user_movie
        target_movie_chunk = target_items_metadata_array[mask]
        u2 = target_movie_chunk[:,0].astype(np.int32)
        r2 = target_movie_chunk[:,2].astype(np.float32)
        common_r1, common_r2 = item_ratings(u1, r1, u2, r2)
        if common_r1.shape[0] != 0 and common_r2.shape[0] != 0:
            similarity_score = compute_similarity_score(common_r1, common_r2)
            if similarity_score > 0.0:
                computed_similarity.append((user_movie, similarity_score))
    most_similar_pairs = sorted(computed_similarity, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:k_similar_user]
    computed_similarity_scores[str(other_movie)] = most_similar_pairs
```

> Benchmarks of the second approach (8.50 minutes > 6 minutes of the first approach)

- Item-Item: Computed similarity scores for 400 movies in: 0:08:50.537102

##### Update - 3rd approach using `iter_rows()` operations

In my third approach, I have better results from the previous two methods, getting results in approximately 2 minutes for user 1 and 400 movies.

```
items_metadata = (
    movie_ratings.filter(
        ~pl.col("movieId").is_in(user_rated_movies)
    )
    .group_by("movieId").agg(
        users_seen_movie=pl.col("userId").unique(),
        user_ratings=pl.col("rating")
    )
)

target_items_metadata = (
    movie_ratings.filter(
        pl.col("movieId").is_in(user_rated_movies)
    ).group_by("movieId").agg(
        users_seen_movie=pl.col("userId").unique(),
        user_ratings=pl.col("rating")
    )
)
```

`items_metadata` is the metadata of `other_movies` not seen by the user 1.

`target_items_metadata` the metadata of the movies rated by user 1. By the term metadata I refer to the two aggregated `.agg()` columns, `users_seen_movie` and `user_ratings`

Finally, I create two for loops using `iter_rows()` method from `polars`

```py
def cosine_similarity_score(array1:np.ndarray, array2:np.ndarray) -> float:
    assert(array1.shape[0] == array2.shape[0])
    a1a2 = 0
    a1a1 = 0
    a2a2 = 0
    for i in range(array1.shape[0]):
        a1a2 += array1[i]*array2[i]
        a1a1 += array1[i]*array1[i]
        a2a2 += array2[i]*array2[i]
    # cos_theta = 1.0
    cos_theta = 0.0
    if a1a1!=0 and a2a2!=0:
        cos_theta = float(a1a2/np.sqrt(a1a1*a2a2))
    return max(0.0, cos_theta)

for row1 in item_metadata.iter_rows():
    computed_similarity: list= []
    for row2 in target_items_metadata.iter_rows():
        r1, r2 = item_ratings(np.asarray(row1[1]), np.asarray(row1[2]), np.asarray(row2[1]), np.asarray(row2[2]))
        if r1.shape[0]!=0 and r2.shape[0]!=0:
            similarity_score = cosine_similarity_score(r1, r2)
        computed_similarity.append((row2[0], similarity_score if similarity_score > 0 else 0))
    computed_similarity_scores[str(row1[0])] = sorted(computed_similarity, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:k_similar_user]
```

> Benchmarks for 400 movies

1. INFO - Item-Item: Computed similarity scores for 400 movies in: 0:01:50
2. ~2 minutes.
3. ~4.5gb of RAM used.

Comment: Did you tried to just use Numba for `compute_similarity_score`? `item_ratings` can certainly be improved by rewriting the function so it uses loops (with an efficient algorithm). Regarding parallelism, I think `item_compute_similarity_scoring_V2` is a good candidate but Numba cannot operate on dataframe, only Numpy arrays, and primitive types. This means that the function needs to be rewritten so to to operate on Numpy arrays first.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have updated my question on how I use ```numba``` in similarity scoring for the benchmarks I posted.

Comment: Is it possible to have the exact code of the 400 movie benchmark you ran? `compute_similarity_score(r1, r2, similarity_metric, logger_obj)` is an error in the current example due missing variables (although they are not needed). Also, `pl.scan_csv("ratings.csv").drop("timestamp").sink_parquet("ratings.parquet")` results in a `110mb` file which could save bandwidth for downloads.

Comment: @jqurious I have edited the code. I think now it will be fine. The file I read is indead a parquet file. Nothing more I do in my benchmarks other than the code provided.

Comment: The function `compute_similarity_score` appears to be equivalent to [sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html). You may find that to be faster, since many people have already optimized it.

Comment: @NickODell I have an obligation not to use built-in functions but rather replicate the cosine's similarity approach with numerical operations as I did.

Comment: Where do I put the `400` limit constraint in order to compare against your timings? (The parquet mention was more for people wanting to download the dataset from the gdrive url - 110mb vs 890mb would be nicer :-D)

Comment: @jqurious it's the variable ```total_unseen_movies=400``` for the list of ```potential_movie_recommendations```..a list with only the ```.unique()``` names for the movies not seen by user1

Comment: Would you mind replacing the screenshots of the terminal with formatted text? You can use [fenced code blocks](/help/formatting) with a `none` language specifier like so: `\`\`\`none`. Text formatted as text is much more readable and renders better across a wide range of devices

Comment: `potential_movie_recommendations` is not defined, nor is `similarity_metric`. Perhaps a better idea is to focus on a single movieId `249408`: https://gist.github.com/cmdlineluser/425ee998e35edbaf4a9e495c04e71850 - The ratings you extract could be described as `INTERSECTION(other_movies['users_seen_movie'], user_movies['users_seen_movie'])` - right?

Comment: @jqurious I have updated my answer to include mores specs like the ```potential_movie_recommendations``` and I removed the parameter ```similarity``` since we don't need it. Also correct your second statement about the ratings.

Comment: @jqurious I have added a second approach without the use of ```map_elements()``` and ```iter_rows()```, starting off from two polars dataframes.

Comment: @NikSp That helped. I had to change some names to make it easier for me to follow: https://gist.github.com/cmdlineluser/c23abd802185d707d54dc8851260ba1f is an initial example. Basically, the for loops/intersection matching are a `join`. The next step would be to remove the numpy stuff and do the scoring with expressions.

Comment: @jqurious I have seen your example. Basically, you create a dataframe with all possible combinations per ```not_seen``` movie. 2 * 62, 3*62 rows, etc...resulting to 560m rows table. Then you apply the for loops of my example. I assume that's a starting point; from the huge dataframe of 560m rows we can now apply expressions to get rid off the numpy computations and for loops. I would appreciate your input on that. Also keep a note that in terms of benchmarks the dataframe of 560m rows changes depending on how many movies a user has seen. The example is only for user 1.

Comment: It was just an attempt to show they are joins. As the data is so big, a "loop" will likely be needed to "chunk" the processing, but you can still express the operation in terms of joins and have Polars do the work. (join/filter) As I think I understand what is actually going on now I should be able to post an answer.

Comment: @jqurious yeah a for loop to filter each time the join table is needed as you say :) (for each unseen movie, like movie=2 in your example)

Comment: you really need the @guvectorize decorator to make a vectorized ufunc otherwise there's not much performance to be gained as there's still an implicit python loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with numba, so
before trying to compare timings, the first thing I would try to do is create a "fully native" Polars approach:

This is a direct translation of the current approach (i.e. it still contains the "double for loop") so it just serves as a baseline attempt.

Because it uses the Lazy API, nothing in the loops is computed.

That is all done when `.collect()` is called (which allows Polars to parallelize the work).

The `> 0.0` filtering for the similarity_score would be done after the results are collected.

```py
input_id = 1

is_user_rating = pl.col("userId") == input_id

can_recommend = (
    pl.col("movieId").is_in(pl.col("movieId").filter(is_user_rating)).not_()
)

cosine_similarity = (
    pl.col('rating').dot('rating_right') /  
    ( pl.col('rating').pow(2).sum().sqrt() * 
      pl.col('rating_right').pow(2).sum().sqrt() ) 
)

user_rated_movies = movie_ratings.filter(is_user_rating).select("movieId").to_series()

potential_movies_to_recommend = (
    movie_ratings.filter(can_recommend).select(pl.col("movieId").unique().sort())
)

# use the Lazy API so we can compute in parallel
df = movie_ratings.lazy()

computed_similarity_scores = []
for other_movie in potential_movies_to_recommend.head(1).to_series(): # .head(N) potential movies
    for user_movie in user_rated_movies:
        score = (
            df.filter(pl.col("movieId") == user_movie)
              .join(
                 df.filter(pl.col("movieId") == other_movie),
                 on = "userId"
              )
              .select(cosine = cosine_similarity)
              .select(user_movie=user_movie, other_movie=other_movie, similarity_score="cosine")
        )
        computed_similarity_scores.append(score)
        
# All scores are computed in parallel
computed_similarity_scores_polars = pl.concat(computed_similarity_scores).collect()
```

```py
shape: (62, 3)
┌────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ user_movie ┆ other_movie ┆ similarity_score │
│ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---              │
│ i32        ┆ i32         ┆ f64              │
╞════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ 2           ┆ 0.95669          │
│ 110        ┆ 2           ┆ 0.950086         │
│ 158        ┆ 2           ┆ 0.957631         │
│ 260        ┆ 2           ┆ 0.945542         │
│ …          ┆ …           ┆ …                │
│ 49647      ┆ 2           ┆ 0.9411           │
│ 52458      ┆ 2           ┆ 0.955353         │
│ 53996      ┆ 2           ┆ 0.930388         │
│ 54259      ┆ 2           ┆ 0.95469          │
└────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Testing `.head(100)` I get `58s` runtime compared to `111s` runtime for your example, memory consumption is the same.

### duckdb

As a comparison, duckdb with `.head(400)` runs in `5s`

```py
import duckdb

df = duckdb.sql("""
with 
   df     as (from 'imdb.parquet'),
   user   as (from df where movieId in (from df select movieId where userId = 1)),
   movies as (from df where movieId not in (from df select movieId where userId = 1)),
   other  as (from df where movieId in (from movies select distinct movieId order by movieId limit 400))
   
from
   user join other using (userId)
   
select   
   user.movieId user_movie,
   other.movieId other_movie,
   list_cosine_similarity(
      list(user.rating), list(other.rating)
   ) similarity_score
   
group by 
   user_movie, other_movie   
order by 
   user_movie, other_movie
""").pl()
```

```py
shape: (24_764, 3)
┌────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────────┐
│ user_movie ┆ other_movie ┆ similarity_score │
│ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---              │
│ i64        ┆ i64         ┆ f64              │
╞════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1          ┆ 2           ┆ 0.95669          │
│ 1          ┆ 3           ┆ 0.941348         │
│ 1          ┆ 4           ┆ 0.92169          │
│ 1          ┆ 5           ┆ 0.943999         │
│ …          ┆ …           ┆ …                │
│ 54259      ┆ 407         ┆ 0.941241         │
│ 54259      ┆ 408         ┆ 0.934745         │
│ 54259      ┆ 409         ┆ 0.937361         │
│ 54259      ┆ 410         ┆ 0.94937          │
└────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────────┘
Elapsed time: 5.02638 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer jqurious. One point is blur to me. In the last part of your answer you suggest to remove the first filter or not?

Comment: Doing `df.join(df.filter(pl.col("movieId") == other_movie))` instead of the `for user_movie in` inner loop runs in `20s` compared to `58s` - but it computes a much larger comparison so requires filtering down to be equivalent. I'm also not sure if it will "scale" for all users. I've removed it for now, i'll need to do more testing.

Comment: @NikSp Maybe you can try `duckdb` and compare the results. `400` with polars/numpy takes too long to run for me but duckdb can do it in 5 seconds. There must be a way to further improve upon this "bruteforce search" approach.

Comment: do you have an example with ```duckdb```?

Comment: @NikSp I added it to the end of the answer.

Comment: Ok I will test the approach with an iteration of user_ids, because you have given it hardcoded ```userId=1``` and I will test it for 10 users to check the results

Comment: Where you define function ```list_cosine_similarity()``` because instead of that I would like to use a custom function that computes other similarities except cosine.

Comment: It's a [native duckdb list function.](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/nested#list-functions) I don't think this approach will be feasible (even though it's much more efficient than doing it in a dataframe) as it duplicates tons of work.

Comment: So you are saying I should not bother using a custom function in duckdb other than the predefined ones, or should I not use the duckdb approach at all?

Comment: From my testing, duckdb seems like the way to go for this task. I just mean the current "algorithm" of "bruteforce searching" is highly inneficient and there must be a better approach that reduces the "search space" and duplication of work.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Just a few notes of benchmarking, the first part with polars does not greatly improve performance. The algorithm is indeed not an optimal one but the description of item-colaborative filtering algorithm (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFi0iPY5fko) is standard.  The duckdb approach is indeed really fast, however since I have 4 similarity metrics (jaccard, cosine, dice, pearson) I will use it for the cosine, and for the other 3 metrics I will go with my approach that takes approximately ~1.50-2 minutes per 400 movies. Thanks a lot for the support. You are the best!

Comment: @NikSp Ah, very interesting! So this task has an actual name - I'll investigate some more. duckdb does have `corr()` https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/aggregates#statistical-aggregates - and `jaccard()` etc, I imagine there is a proper way to model all of this using it (I only have basic skills with it). This answer should probably be removed (or at least the Polars stuff) as it seems like this task is just not suited for dataframes at all and isn't really a good reflection of "Polars usage".

Comment: I will post later today or tomorrow my approach with polars and .iter_rows() that takes 1.5 minutes for 400 movies. Do you think that splitting the 400 movies into 4 batches (i.e. 100 movies per batch) and write on disk the results per 100 movies could potentially increase the computation complexity for Polars? Maybe polars works better with more data much like as Spark

Comment: @NikSp I'm not sure. It seems like one of the main issues is work duplication? e.g. `df.filter(pl.col("movieId") == other_movie)` ends up running thousands (millions?) of times for the same movieId. `df.group_by("movieId").agg("userId")` is fast and tells you all connected users per movie, but I'm not sure how to express the next step efficiently. It's like a graph problem e.g. https://snap.stanford.edu/agm/ - It also seems related to "nearest neighbor/vector searching" which people seem to use `faiss` + GPUs for, but I don't know much on the topic really so I may be off base.

Comment: the progress and the discussion already suffice to answer the question asked. So we can maybe discuss our conversation via email. You may find me at nickosspan@gmail.com. I will look into your suggestions but for now I will stick polars, numba and maybe UDF functions in DuckDB.

Comment: I have added an edit using ```iter_rows()``` as promised. The best performance after duckdb

Comment: @NikSp you can use the plugin that I've built for Polars to do these distance measures or similarity functions natively, plugin is called: Polars-distance.

Comment: @elgreco I will check it out from https://ion-elgreco.github.io/polars-distance/usage/. Thanks!